# SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, sqlsrv

I'm using the following PHP connection file to connect to my SQL Server database.

```
<?php
$servername = "...";
$username = "...";
$password = "";
$dbname = "...";

try {
   $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$servername;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
   echo "Connected to $dbname at $servername successfully.";
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
   die ("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I keep getting this error that says:

> "SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Login failed for user $username".

I have downloaded latest version of ODBC 17 and 18 and I expected this to resolve this issue, but it hasn't. My SQL Server authentication is set to SQL Server and Windows Authentication also.

Comment: So which type of login are you trying to use here? This style of connection will only work with SQL Server logins - usernames and passwords that are not Azure/Active Directory/Windows accounts.

Comment: If you have access to the target SQL Server by another means, such as SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), have you checked the Error Logs yet? Look for Error 14856 messages, take note of the `State` number mentioned, and compare it against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the actual cause of the login failure.

Answer (score 0):

if using laravel, in your .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=DESKTOP-91MB9QU\TESTSQLSERVER
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=laravel_test
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD='mypassword'
```

and you can use it. pay attention to DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv and DB_HOST must has format of "PC-name\SQL-server-name" and DB_PORT has null value.

you can use similar way to pure php code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in C++. It helped me to catch another Exception "CDBException".

```
        catch (CDBException* p)
        {
            cout << "Login failed!" << endl;
        }
```

For your code sth like this

```
        catch (CDBException $pe) {
            die ("Could not connect to the database");
}
```

Maybe its the same Exception name but there should be at least a similar one as mine.
After that my code worked. Hope it helps you.